# In Cinderella (1950), is Cinderella's full name "Princess Cinderella Charming"?

Tags: cinderella-1950

Cinderella married Prince Charming in the [original Disney animation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0042332/) (1950), and in [*Descendants*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3440298/), she has a son called Chad Charming.
Does that mean her name is actually Cinderella Charming?

Her Disney Wiki page had that as her full name, but it got deleted.

And if that **is** her full name, would she be an example of a Princess Charming?

Comment: Impossible to infer from the information you give here.  People can retain their birth name. Also Royal Titles and names often follow their own rule, see Princess Michael of Kent (married to Prince Michael of Kent).  Yeah, her name is Marie Christine, but her title isn't Princess Marie Christine.

Comment: "Her Disney Wiki page had that as her full name, but it got deleted." Have you asked them why they did that? I know that some of your questions on SciFi.SE were attempts to justify wiki edits elsewhere.

Comment: Her name would be Ella or anything like that, Cinderella is more of a mean nickname but I guess she just rides with it for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a rough analogy from UK tradition, Charming would be the Prince's **first** name, not his last/family name.

Simple ref: Prince Charles.
He is Charles Windsor, but 'Prince Charles' is how he is referred to [if not being highly formal, with HRH, Prince of Wales, Duke of Cornwall...etc] so I'd say someone made a proper boo-boo calling the son Chad Charming [though presumably they did it because Prince Charming has no known last name].

So... no.
She would be ***titled*** Princess Cinderella, ***named*** Cinderella [family name of the current Royal family, unknown as it was never written down in the original fairy tale, or alternatively her original family name]
It is generally accepted that British Royals don't really have a family name and they are rarely referred to by it. The current accepted wisdom is to use 'Windsor' if you feel you need to use one at all. Windsor itself is an invented name, chosen because [Saxe-Coburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Saxe-Coburg_and_Gotha#United_Kingdom) felt a bit 'German' at the time of WWI.